# I try to use Kivy in nuke scripts edit but it casts 'unable to find any valuable Text provider at all'

Tags: python, kivy, nuke

Here is my env setting

```
set NUKE_PATH=T:\___TEMP\Pipeline\nuke\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-4.0.0-py2.7-win-amd64.egg;
               C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip;
               C:\Python27\lib;
               C:\Python27\lib\plat-win;
               C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;
               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\modules;
               C:\Users\Isaac\.kivy\mods
```

And it always says

```
  sdl2  -ImportError:DLL load failed
  pil -ImportError:DLL load failed
  unable to find any valuable Text provider at all Abort
```

When I type

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

The nuke just shut down

these code works fine in my Pycharm.
Have you seen this problem before? 
Does Nuke scripts edit has any special rules about finding env?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy deps add their folders to the PATH, so I presume Nuke needs the same thing, therefore add their path manually:

```
set NUKE_PATH=%NUKE_PATH%;<python dir>\share\<dep>\bin
```

replace with python folder and dependency names (multiple folders).